# How to save a 3D array as multiple 2D arrays per line in txt file?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a python function that outputs a 3D list:

```
[
[[1,2], [3,4,5]]
[1,5,6], [1,3]]
...
]
```

I want to be able to save it to a txt file like this:

```
[[1,2], [3,4,5]]
[[1,5,6], [1,3]]
...
```

with one 2D list per line. I also want to be able to read the result again.

Does anyone know how to do this? (I looked online at some other resources but couldn't exactly find this)
I am a little new to python so would appreciate any help!

Comment: If you want to read the results back, why not use `pickle`?

Comment: @DYZ I'm not super familiar with pickle. Is there a code example I could play around with? Thank you!!

Comment: There are tons of examples online. Just google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lst = [[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]]]
with open("output.txt", "w") as outfile:
    for line in lst:
        outfile.write(str(line) + "\n")
```

One way to do it.

```
import ast
res = []
with open("output.txt", "r") as inp:
    for line in inp.readlines():
        res.append(ast.literal_eval(line))
print(res)
```

To read it back.

But as @DYZ suggested, pickle is a better way to do it. Or even json.
Pickle docs are [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html).